# Get a list of categories that are related to posts

Tags: posts, categories

I use the following code to get a list of all categories:

```
$args = array(
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'orderby'    => 'name'
);
wp_list_categories($args);
```

However, I want a list that only lists categories related to posts. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `'hide_empty' => 1,`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Display Categories Assigned to a post -->

                    <?php $taxonomy = 'category';

                    // Get the term IDs assigned to post.
                    $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

                    // Separator between links.
                    $separator = ',';
 if ( ! empty( $post_terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {

                        $gterms = wp_list_categories( array(
                            'title_li' => '',
                            'style'    => 'none',
                            'echo'     => false,
                            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                            'include'  => $term_ids,
                            'child_of' => 193
                        ) );

                        $gterms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $gterms ) ), $separator );
                    }
```

put your parent cat id, for example, I have genre parent category, it has a lot of children, to display the children that are related to the current post you're in put the id of the parent which is genre.
to output it plz use `<?php echo $gterms; ?>`

Comment: Thank you! However, what I really want to achieve is, to get every category that is used by any post. So I want a list of categories, that are generally used by posts.

Comment: you mean the most used categories?!